Move primary key partitions from unique index on parent table to primary key on parent table
I have a partitioned table. It has primary keys on the children. And it has a matching unique index on the parent, which acts as the parent index of the indexes of the primary keys on the partitions. I want to change the unique index on the parent into a primary key constraint without recreating the primary keys on all children. All I tried failed. Is there a way?
Working example to reproduce the problem:
create table tst (id int,partition_num int) partition by list (partition_num);
create table tst_1 partition of tst for values in (1);
create table tst_2 partition of tst for values in (2);
alter table tst_1 add constraint tst_pk_1 primary key (id,partition_num);
alter table tst_2 add constraint tst_pk_2 primary key (id,partition_num);
create unique index tst_ui1 on tst (id,partition_num);

select relispartition from pg_class where relname = 'tst_pk_1'; -- true

dbname=> \d+ tst
                                        Partitioned table "public.tst"
    Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer |           |          |         | plain   |             |              |
 partition_num | integer |           |          |         | plain   |             |              |
Partition key: LIST (partition_num)
Indexes:
    "tst_ui1" UNIQUE, btree (id, partition_num)
Partitions: tst_1 FOR VALUES IN (1),
            tst_2 FOR VALUES IN (2)


dbname=> \d+ tst_1
                                             Table "public.tst_1"
    Column     |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage | Compression | Stats target | Description
---------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------+---------+-------------+--------------+-------------
 id            | integer |           | not null |         | plain   |             |              |
 partition_num | integer |           | not null |         | plain   |             |              |
Partition of: tst FOR VALUES IN (1)
Partition constraint: ((partition_num IS NOT NULL) AND (partition_num = 1))
Indexes:
    "tst_pk_1" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id, partition_num)
Access method: heap


The solution looks wild, but is really simple:

detach all partitions from the partitioned table

drop the unique index on the partitioned table, which won't affect the primary keys on the former partitions

reattach the partitions to the partitioned table

create the primary key on the partitioned table


Detaching and attaching the tables can be a quick operation, so you could do all that with a very short down time or even in a single database transaction. To speed up ALTER TABLE ... ATTACH PARTITION, add a check constraint that exactly corresponds to the partitioning constraint, so that PostgreSQL doesn't have to scan the partition if all rows match the partitioning constraint.

There is always room for improvement...

(Fixing my comment from above) TYVM - I will go that route, seems to be a bit of a missing feature though, to not be able to remove a parent index without removing the children.
